# Can't find who sets http_proxy environment variable on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10,

When running in terminal:

```
env | grep proxy
```

I get:

```
https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8888/
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

I can't find who sets these environment variables.

I've tried all the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) and could not find anything.
Tried different shells / terminals. Variables are always there.

Any idea what else can it be?

Comment: If you can't find the source, nuke it with `unset https_proxy http_proxy` in the appropriate shell startup file.

Comment: This is what I would probably end up doing. But it does not feel right.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

No luck in checking all the usual suspects? Then it's time to use the big gun:

```
find /etc $HOME /usr/local -type f | xargs grep -E 'https?_proxy'
```

Run this as root. Add directories to your liking.

Comment: Didn't find anything :\

Comment: @Amir Hmm. My last guess would be that it's compiled into one of the executables, anywhere from init, getty or login. Try `string -a executable | grep proxy` on them. Does Ubuntu use systemd? Then check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

An environment variable in your current shell can only be set in the parent process, or in a file sourced by your shell. I would start by turning on the shell trace in the respective rc-files which are sourced when you log in, in your home directory. This is also the place where I would verify whether the environment variables is already set at this point (which would mean that it was set by the global initialization process, for instance in the rc files which reside in /etc). Now log in and check the output.

If the environment variable is already set initially, you can't do much except bugging your admin that he should remove it (which probably won't work). If it is not set initially, you need to look through the output of the shell trace, until you either find the point, where the variable is set, or where you see that some malicious script turns off the trace.

Since you didn't give any information, which shell you are using, I can't go into deeper detail.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using Terminator with Zshell. As I originally said, I tried using  the native terminal with bash, and I still see those vars.

Comment: I've never used Terminator, but I suspect that the variables are either already set in the process which starts Terminator, or Terminator sets it. Hence I suggest that you proceed with my suggestion, and in particular make sure that you print the value of these variables in your zsh initialization files. After this, we can narrow the search further.

Answer (score 0):

In my case those env variables were set by Fiddler web debugger and I was able to remove them manually by editing `~/.bashrc` file. There are 2 lines with `export http(s)_proxy...` located at the end of this file. Hope that it helps!